# Find a positive integer n such that P (n, 2) = 110.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm revising for an exam on permutation. I saw this question

> Find a positive integer n such that P (n, 2) = 110.

The answer

[image]

I don't understand how **n!** became **(n-1)n** when we don't know what n is. I need help. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand that $n! = (n-2)!(n-1)n$ (assuming of course $n \ge 2$)?  Then cancel the $(n-2)!$ in numerator and denominator.

Comment: yes. but why are we assuming its >= 2. I'm not getting it yet @RobertIsrael

Comment: @Calypso:  clearly $n=0,1$ don't work, so $n$ must be at least $2$

Comment: Ooooh, it feels like a sudden state of epiphany. I understand now. Thanks @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$n!=(n)(n-1)!=(n)(n-1)(n-2)!$$

Answer (score 0):

For integers, factorials have the property

$$
n! = n \cdot (n - 1)!
$$

Hence you have $n = n\cdot (n-1)! = n(n-1)\cdot (n-2)!$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take example - You have 5!

Then 5! = 5 × 4!

We stop expanding it up to 4!

We subtract 1 from 5 to get 4!

Suppose you have n instead of 5 then you subtract 1 from n. So we have now (n-1)!

Therefore,

n! = n × (n - 1)!

If further want to expand subtract 1 from factorial term again.

n! = n × (n - 1) × (n - 2)!

Comment: Still doubt please ask.